# If $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence then there exists an $M$ such that for all $n \ge M$ we have $|x_{n+1}-x_n| \le |x_n-x_{n-1}|$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Question: True /False prove or find a counterexample: If $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence then there exists an $M$ such that for all $n \ge M$ we have $|x_{n+1}-x_n| \le |x_n-x_{n-1}|$.

I think this is true because $|x_{n+1}-x_n| < \varepsilon$ is true for $n\ge M$, but $|x_n-x_{n-1}|< \varepsilon$ is not necessarily true for $n\ge M$. This means that there is chance that $|x_{n+1}-x_n|<|x_n-x_{n-1}|$.

Is this correct? and if it is, is it enough to justify that the statement is true?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're not asked to prove or disprove that "there's a chance that" it's true. Is it **always** true (i.e., for **every** Cauchy sequence) or not (i.e., it's false for at least one Cauchy sequence).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:   consider the sequence $\,\dfrac{1}{1},\dfrac{1}{1},\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2},\ldots\dfrac{1}{n},\dfrac{1}{n},\ldots\,$

Comment: I think you give this sequence as an counter example. We know that $|x_{n+1}-x_n| < \varepsilon$ for sure, and your example show that $|x_n-x_{n-1}|$ can be either 0 or some +ve real number. So, the inequality does not hold. Am I interpreting your example correct?

Comment: @SihyunKim Right, this is a counterexample that proves the proposition false.